# Single image can't uploading in database

Tags: java, android, sql, imageview

When i am trying to upload image and store in database it is not storing the data or image.

In my application i have some EditText and 6 ImageView.

When i am inserting all Six image then it is storing in database but when i upload one or two image then it is not working

Here the api

```
    <?php
            header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
            $pannm = $_POST['abc'];
            $bpan = base64_decode($_POST['eabc']);
            if($pannm!='') {
            $filename1 = time().'_'.$pannm;
            $ppan = 'upload/';
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['eabc']['tmp_name'], $ppan);
            $path1 = "upload/$filename1";
            $file1 = fopen('upload/'.$filename1, 'wb');
            fwrite($file1, $bpan);  
            fclose($file1);
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Successfully Added.";
            echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Here the code :-

**main.java**

```
    buy_image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            selectImage();
            edit.putInt("ImageID", 1);
            edit.commit();


        }
    });

public void selectImage()
{
    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    i.putExtra("crop", "true");
    i.putExtra("outputX", 512);
    i.putExtra("outputY", 512);
    i.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    i.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    i.putExtra("scale", true);
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && null != data)
    {
        final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1200000; // 1.2MP

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        int imgid = 0;
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        Log.d("Value", picturePath);
        fileName = new File(picturePath).getName();
        // imgname.setText(fileName);

        String fileNameSegments[] = picturePath.split("/");
        fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];

        // MyParams.put("filename", fileName);
        Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);

        sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Image ID", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        imgid = sp.getInt("ImageID", 0);
        Log.d("IMGID",Integer.toString(imgid));

        BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize=5;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, stream);

        byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        // Encode Image to String
        encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
        //MyParams.put(I_IMA, encodedString);

        if(imgid == 1) {
            buy_image1.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
            img1 = fileName;
            encodedStringIMG1 = encodedString;
        }
        else if(imgid == 2) {
            buy_image2.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
            img2 = fileName;
            encodedStringIMG2 = encodedString;
        }
        if(imgid == 3) {
            buy_image3.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
            img3 = fileName;
            encodedStringIMG3 = encodedString;
        }
        else if(imgid == 4) {
            buy_image4.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
            img4 = fileName;
            encodedStringIMG4 = encodedString;
        }
        if(imgid == 5) {
            buy_image5.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
            img5 = fileName;
            encodedStringIMG5 = encodedString;
        }
        else if(imgid == 6) {
            buy_image6.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
            img6 = fileName;
            encodedStringIMG6 = encodedString;
        }
        else{
            Log.d("IMGID","IMAGE ID IS 0");
        }
}
private void service(
        String strwodname, String strfirm, String strowner,
        String strpartner1, String strpartner2, String strbranch,
        String strcontactperson, String strcontact,
        String strwhatsapp, String stremail, String strspinnercity,
        String straddress, String opendate1, String birthdate, String ani,
        String strpancard, String strtinnumber, String strbankname, String strbankholdername
        ,String strbankac,String strbankcity, String strifsccode,String strsecuritycheque,String strrefrence1,
        String strrefrence2,String strremarks,String i1,String encode1,String i2,String encode2,String i3,String encode3,String i4,
        String encode4,String i5,String encode5,String i6,String encode6
  ) {


      /*  */
        class AddVisitclass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


                HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();


                param.put("wname", params[0]);
                /*param.put("firm", params[1]);
                param.put("oname", params[2]);
                param.put("pname1", params[3]);
                param.put("pname2", params[4]);
                */param.put("branch", params[1]);
                param.put("cname", params[2]);
                param.put("contact", params[3]);
                param.put("whatsapp", params[4]);
                param.put("email", params[5]);
                param.put("city", params[6]);
                param.put("address", params[7]);
                param.put("bdate", params[8]);
                param.put("odate", params[9]);
                param.put("adate", params[10]);
                param.put("pancard", params[11]);
                param.put("tinno", params[12]);
                param.put("bnm", params[13]);
                param.put("bank_ac_holder", params[14]);
                param.put("bank_ac_no", params[15]);
                param.put("bcity", params[16]);
                param.put("ifsc_code", params[17]);
                param.put("cheque", params[18]);
                param.put("ref1", params[19]);
                param.put("ref2", params[20]);
                param.put("remarks", params[21]);

                param.put("pan", params[22]);
                param.put("epan", params[23]);
                param.put("aadhar", params[24]);
                param.put("eaadhar", params[25]);
                param.put("light", params[26]);
                param.put("elight", params[27]);
                param.put("vat", params[28]);
                param.put("evat", params[29]);
                param.put("vcard", params[30]);
                param.put("evcard", params[31]);
                param.put("shop", params[32]);
                param.put("eshop", params[33]);



                param.put("username",uid);
                String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(url_addwod, param);
//                Log.d("Result", result);
                Log.d("Data", param.toString());
                return result;
            }
            //@Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                //loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "W.O.D. added successfully...!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               /* FragmentTransaction t = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                TabFragment mFrag = new TabFragment();
                t.replace(com.Weal.sachin.omcom.R.id.framelayout, mFrag);
                t.commit();
*/
            }
        }
        AddVisitclass regi = new AddVisitclass();
        regi.execute(strwodname,strbranch,strcontactperson,strcontact,strwhatsapp,stremail,
                strspinnercity,straddress,opendate1,birthdate,ani,strpancard,strtinnumber,strbankname,strbankholdername,strbankac,
                strbankcity, strifsccode,strsecuritycheque,strrefrence1,strrefrence2,strremarks,i1,encode1,i2,encode2
                ,i3,encode3,i4,encode4,i5,encode5,i6,encode6);


    }
```

In  Add Button i call addproperty() method.

Comment: [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also provide any errors that are being thrown

Comment: no errors are shown in logcat.

Comment: the problem is with server side code not the android code i think

Comment: please give api too so we can look where error is @Andie